# Why does * in my Java calculator not work

Tags: java, calculator

So I'm working on a really simple java calculator without any scanner.
The calculator can calculate  +, -, / and *
Every operator works, except * but I cant figure out why

```java
public class Calculator2 {
    public static void main(String[] args){

      
        double ersteZahl = Double.parseDouble(args[0]);


       
        double zweiteZahl = Double.parseDouble(args[2]);
       
        char operator = args[1].charAt(0);


        switch (operator) {

            case '+':
                System.out.println(ersteZahl + zweiteZahl);
                break;

            case '-':
                System.out.println(ersteZahl - zweiteZahl);
                break;

            case '*':
                System.out.println(ersteZahl * zweiteZahl);
                break;

            case '/':
                System.out.println(ersteZahl / zweiteZahl);
                break;

        }
    }
}
```

This is the error when I try to multiply something

```
PS C:\Users\Besitzer\onedrive\desktop\java> java Calculator2 10 * 2
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "Calculator.java"
        at java.base/jdk.internal.math.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:2054)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.math.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(FloatingDecimal.java:110)
        at java.base/java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:651)
        at Calculator2.main(Calculator2.java:10)
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: If you want to use `*` on the command line, it must be single-quoted else it's a glob

Comment: The error in the image is generated from one of the parseDouble() statements you have. Maybe try to print the arguments before parsing them and take a look at what exactly you are parsing.

Comment: @XPModder the problem is that due to shell globbing, `"Calculator.java"` ends up in `args[2]`. So the `*` needs to be escaped in the shell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would say that the problem is not in your program, but in your operating system (OS).

I am going to assume that you execute this from a Linux shell, although other OSes may have a similar issue.

When you run the command line `java Calculator2 10 * 2` the OS is going to expand the `*` character into all file names in the current folder. This happens *before* your program even starts running so by the time your main function gets called, `args` will be something like [`10`, `Calculator2.java`, `mynotes.txt`,  `some_other_file.obj`, `xyz.bat`, `2`]. Normally this is what you want: you don't want `rm *` to delete a file called `*` but actually have it work on all file names in the folder.

You can verify this by writing a test application that prints your arguments, actually you should add error handling anyway, so that instead of crashing the program shows something like *Invalid calculation: expected a number for argument 2 but got 'mynotes.txt')*

Try running it as `java Calculator 10 '*' 2`. Or in your code use another character like `x` for multiplication.

Comment: I would suggest to use single quotes instead of double quotes, but if it works with one of those, it's fine

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Single quotes cause the same error

Comment: @AmirKhan what does your commandline now look like? And using the debugger, what values are you receiving in `args`?

Comment: I just started programming yestderday so Ive really  limitied knowledge about this. When I use is with single quotes nothing happens, the commandline looks the same

Comment: @AmirKhan then this is a good time to learn how to debug :-) Find out how to use breakpoints in your IDE (integrated development environment) or start by simply printing `args[0]`, `args[1]` and `args[2]` to the screen at the start of the program.